# display disabled option element - html drop down form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down html form and would like to display the `disabled=disabled` element (view the edit below)
At first initial glance, the form skips the `disabled` element and displays "option 1".

```
<select>
    <option disabled='disabled'>Title</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Is this possible with just `html` or `css`?
If not then how about `jQuery` or `javascript`?

**Edit**
Would like the form to look like this 
[image]
Currently it looks like 
[image]

Comment: @OneTrickPony can you elaborate please

Comment: You have posted the right answer as your question.

Comment: @t q: what's the question here exactly? You want to disable a certain option with javascript?

Comment: @OneTrickPony When the user views the form I would like them to se the `disabled` option, so in my case they would see "Visible Title" rather than 'Option 1' as their first choice.  But because it is disabled they would NOT be able to click this element.

Comment: Disabled options are displayed, but greyed out and unselectable.

Comment: will redo my question, didnt think this would cause so much confusion,  my appologies

Comment: @Barmar yes and i would like to display that disabled, greyed out element

Comment: That's what `disabled='disabled'` should do. If you're not seeing the greyed option, there's a problem with your browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `selected="selected"` to your first option.

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled='disabled'>Visible Title</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7sEyV/)**